# How to access an environment variable that's a bash array from a Ruby ERB script?

Tags: ruby, bash, environment-variables, erb

How does one loop through an environment variable that is a bash array in a Ruby ERB?

I'm aware that this can be done with arguments anyway

```
 <%= @args[x] %>
```

And you can get to Environment Variables this way:

```
 <%= ENV["PATH"] %>
```

But how do you get to an array?

```
 <%= ENV["MR_BASH_ARRAY"] %>
```

and then loop it around...

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as,

```
MR_BASH_ARRAY:
  '1': 'Value-1'
  '2': 'Value-2'
  '3': 'Value-3'
```

And get your array as `ENV['MR_BASH_ARRAY'].values`